# Не работает onclick внутри object в Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, объекты, google-chrome

Есть скрипт, а точнее плеер с видео:

```
<object onclick="startPart();"  id="pl6" name="pl6" classid="----" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,2,0,0" width="660" height="400"><param name="movie" value="/player.swf"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000"><param name="flashvars" value="pl=1776"><embed onclick="startPart();" name="pl6" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" src="/player.swf" width="660" height="400" wmode="opaque" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" bgcolor="#000000" flashvars="pl=1776"></embed></object>
```

Добавил к нему через `onclick` который вызывает функцию отсчета и вывода через CSS `display:none`:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function startPart(){
   setTimeout("timer()", 1000);}

function timer(){
 var obj=document.getElementById('close2');
 obj.innerHTML--;

 if(obj.innerHTML==0){
document.getElementById("close1").innerHTML= '<style>#close1 {display:block;} #close2 {display:none;}</style>';
setTimeout(function(){},1000);}
 else{setTimeout(timer,1000);}}
</script>
```

На опере, мазиле работает как часы, а на хроме ни в какую.

Может есть работающая альтернатива для хрома? :(

С `<div>` не вариант так как при активации JS должен и активироваться плеер с видео.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй обернуть в **div** и повесить событие на него. И используй **mousedown** вместо **click**. В хроме работает: http://jsfiddle.net/j3Y8h/1/.

Comment: вот что придумал 
<script>
$('#pladform1776').mousedown(function(){
   $(document).ready(function() {do_counter();});
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('b').fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn(function(){$(this).html('<style>#close1 {display:block;} #counter2 {display:none;}</style>')
});
   }); 
});   
 </script>
только вот он и на правый клик и на левый реагирует, а надо только левый, как сделать?

Comment: Добавь в начало обработчика события следующую строчку:
if (e.which != 1) return false;//точно работает в ie 10 и хроме

И не нужно оборачивать каждый кусок кода в ready, оберни $('#pladform1776').mousedown() и все, дальше не нужно использовать ready